# ng-if -> multiple 'OR' condition is not working

Tags: angularjs

```
ng-if="self_employment.business_type != 'Trust' || self_employment.business_type !== 'Partnership'"
```

Comment: You need to provide your controller logic if you want some help.

Comment: The code doesn't look wrong. You must have a problem with your variable `self_employment`. Check it with `console.log(self_employment);` in your console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use != instead of !==  :

```
ng-if="self_employment.business_type != 'Trust' || self_employment.business_type != 'Partnership'"
```

Answer (score 0):

When You face this kind of problems, First check the object is **defined** or not. print the **{{self_employment.business_type}}** in the Html/console. If it is coming **"trust/partnership"** then it is in **lowercase**. if it is **lowercase** it may cause to fail the condition.

```
"trust" === "Trust" // false
"trust" == "Trust"  // false
"trust" == "trust"  // true
```

Comment: Noo all are upper case and also i checked console as well as in html.but it doesnt work